# AWS Amplify: Auth has not yet been added to this project

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm not sure what I did (removed `node_modules` and reinstalled?) but I used to have auth configured for my AWS Amplify (v0.1.42) project and now it's gone.

My `.amplifyrc` is configured correctly:

```
{
    "providers": {
        "awscloudformation": {
            "AuthRoleName": "xxx",
            "UnauthRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx",
            "AuthRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx",
            "Region": "us-east-1",
            "DeploymentBucketName": "xxx",
            "UnauthRoleName": "xxx",
            "StackName": "xxx",
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:xxx:stack/xxx/xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

I have an existing `amplify/` directory with `auth` as part of the `backend` and `#current-cloud-backend`. I also have a generated `src/aws-exports.js`:

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile =  {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-1:xxx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-1_xxx",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxx"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

All of the information is correct, however when I try to execute amplify cli commands it acts like I'm a brand new user. How can I get the amplify cli to use the existing configuration in my project?

This is incredibly frustrating because I can't really afford to create everything from scratch again.

Comment: Have you tried running `amplify env pull`?

Comment: That just brings up the help menu. I'm on v0.1.42, I'll update my question with that info.